# Query degenerates into a PK scan when order by is added

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have a query that results in a couple of rows and executes immediately:

```
explain (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select *
          from  mcqueen_base_video as v1 
            left join mcqueen_base_visit as v2 on v1.visit_id = v2.id
          where v2.protocol_id = 191 and v1.is_valid = TRUE
          limit 10;
                                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.99..6.94 rows=10 width=539) (actual time=25.779..25.779 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2791 read=30
   I/O Timings: read=21.078
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..49163.60 rows=82648 width=539) (actual time=25.777..25.777 rows=0 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=2791 read=30
         I/O Timings: read=21.078
         ->  Index Scan using mcqueen_base_visit_be92d870 on mcqueen_base_visit v2  (cost=0.42..571.01 rows=1012 width=69) (actual time=2.158..2.189 rows=33 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (protocol_id = 191)
               Buffers: shared hit=10 read=1
               I/O Timings: read=2.124
         ->  Index Scan using mcqueen_base_video_ea367887 on mcqueen_base_video v1  (cost=0.56..46.91 rows=111 width=470) (actual time=0.713..0.713 rows=0 loops=33)
               Index Cond: (visit_id = v2.id)
               Filter: is_valid
               Rows Removed by Filter: 106
               Buffers: shared hit=2781 read=29
               I/O Timings: read=18.954
 Planning time: 8.153 ms
 Execution time: 26.149 ms
```

But if I add an `order by`, the PK scan drops the `Index Cond` and scans the full primary key:

```
explain (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select *
          from  mcqueen_base_video as v1 
            left join mcqueen_base_visit as v2 on v1.visit_id = v2.id
          where v2.protocol_id = 191 and v1.is_valid = TRUE
          order by v1.id limit 10;
QUERY PLAN                                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.99..2834.98 rows=10 width=543) (actual time=702992.647..702992.647 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=211522273 read=4584467 dirtied=934
   I/O Timings: read=500327.759
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..23422395.38 rows=82648 width=543) (actual time=702992.417..702992.417 rows=0 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=211522273 read=4584467 dirtied=934
         I/O Timings: read=500327.759
         ->  Index Scan using mcqueen_base_video_pkey on mcqueen_base_video v1  (cost=0.56..3192475.70 rows=44436676 width=470) (actual time=0.086..565910.358 rows=44489757 loops=1)
               Filter: is_valid
               Rows Removed by Filter: 2258156
               Buffers: shared hit=33241260 read=4570000 dirtied=934
               I/O Timings: read=498179.392
         ->  Index Scan using mcqueen_base_visit_pkey on mcqueen_base_visit v2  (cost=0.42..0.45 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=44489757)
               Index Cond: (id = v1.visit_id)
               Filter: (protocol_id = 191)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
               Buffers: shared hit=178281013 read=14467
               I/O Timings: read=2148.367
 Planning time: 0.477 ms
 Execution time: 702993.085 ms
```

This query is generated by Django's ORM and the reason for the `order by v1.id limit 10` is the way that django does pagination.

I know that `order by/limit` is a terrible way to paginate large datasets, but even though the table is large, the filters usually result in small result sets. The problem is that the query planner decides to do an index scan and filter on `is_valid` before determining the join results.

I've already tried adding an index on `visit_id,is_valid` but that did not alter the query plan.

If I manually resolve the join into an ID list and use that as in `IN` clause, the query executes immediately:

```
explain select *
          from  mcqueen_base_video as v1
          where v1.visit_id in (501201) and v1.is_valid = TRUE
          order by v1.id limit 10;
QUERY PLAN                                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=48.29..48.31 rows=10 width=470)
   ->  Sort  (cost=48.29..48.56 rows=109 width=470)
         Sort Key: id
         ->  Index Scan using mcqueen_base_video_ea367887 on mcqueen_base_video v1  (cost=0.56..45.93 rows=109 width=470)
               Index Cond: (visit_id = 501201)
               Filter: is_valid
```

I may be able to hack up the ORM to force that behavior, but I was hoping there was some postgres tuning I might be able to do to get the query planner to do that resolution for me (Note: replacing the `IN` clause with a subselect results in the same query plan as the join.)

**EDIT**: added `(ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` to `EXPLAIN` and showing the query plan for the query without the `order by` as well.

Comment: Please show EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), not just EXPLAIN.

Comment: There two queries are not the same, the first one is using a LEFT JOIN that turns into an INNER JOIN because of the WHERE conditions, and the second one is just a single table. Besides that, I don't see any problem in your topic, just an observation.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Correct, the second one is a different query, in that the inner left join which constrains the result set from the first table is replaced with the IDs that the join would have produced. Disregarding that `*` will be a different number of columns the resulting rows from the first table are the same

Comment: @jjanes Added `ANALYZE, BUFFERS` and also showing the fast version without the `order by`.

Comment: Your estimates are quite off.  Does doing a VACUUM ANALYZE on both tables change anything much?

Comment: I thought i'd done `VACUUM ANALYZE` before, but re-did it to be certain. Numbers changed a bit, but made no useful difference. Still scanning the PK without applying the index condition